# Allowed wiring methods for running power between two structures above a walkway

Tags: electrical

US, Southern CA, NEC 2017

I have a pergola 5ft away from an exterior wall that I'd like to run power to. Are there wiring methods that would allow power to be run through the air between two structures and above a walkway? If so, what would the code requirements/limitations be?

Things I have considered:

- burying conduit - not an option due to an existing concrete floor
- surface conduit - I'd like to avoid adding anything to the floor as there is an active walkway

**Edit:** It seems like conduit could be used above the walkway if it was supported and protected properly. The building-side has eaves that extend 2ft into the gap, so the actual air-space that would need to be crossed is closer to 3ft, not the entire 5ft span.

Comment: How much power do you want at your pergola?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the only thing that this would be used for is adding lights to the pergola without needing to have an extension cord laying about. There is an existing junction box on the wall adjacent to the pergola, 6ft above the ground for a outdoor light, so this would be an extension of that branch circuit.

Comment: Flexible conduit? Why not rigid conduit? One 10' stick of metal conduit, cut it down to size.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I'd like flexible conduit for two reasons: 1) flex will allow for movement between the two structures in the event of the earthquake and 2) the eaves end at a height lower than where the run would continue at the pergola, and flex conduit means less tricky bending

Comment: In a quick search I found https://www.jadelearning.com/blog/securing-and-supporting-cables-and-raceways-2/ which covers rigid (EMT and PVC) but not flex.

Comment: Please don't add new questions to existing ones. It invalidates existing answers and can make your original question "too broad". Instead, please ask a whole new question and include a link back to this one for additional background. No one will think poorly of you for asking multiple questions about the same project, but we will frown on ever expanding, too broad questions.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for the advice, I've removed the new questions about flexible conduit and accepted ThreePhaseEel's answer, as I believe it answers the information I was looking for in my original question

Comment: Have you considered just building an awning between the two buildings?  That would provide a path out of the rain, and then electrical could be installed on top of or through it.

Comment: @NateS. thanks, adding an awning would provide support for a raceway, but doesn't inform code-compliant methods for the situation in my original question: bringing power across a small gap without supports

Comment: @CJC, for sure; I thought ThreePhase convered that well, so I didn't have any more to add in that regard.  I just suggested an awning as a possible alternative (and probably what I'd do if it were my house, since I don't like walking in the rain haha).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What you're after is called *messenger supported wiring*, and it's an established part of the NEC

The good news is that what you're after is quite possible within the NEC, using a wiring method called *messenger supported wiring*.  In short, this involves suspending a steel *messenger wire* between the two structures, and then using that messenger to support electrical cables or wires.  This works much the same way as overhead utility wiring; in fact, you could use a length of utility triplex for this job, but it'd be more trouble than its worth.

The bad news is that like an overhead utility service drop, you'll need to get some elevation on these wires to keep people from blundering into them face-first.  NEC 225.18 requires the lowest point of the wire to be at a minimum of 10' from the ground in a typical situation (using triplex). While this is less than what'd be required for an actual utility service drop, it would require some sort of mast.

However, given that you'll be running a UF cable on the messenger in all likelihood, you can use a metal strut channel or wood pole at each end with the UF and messenger attached to them instead of conduit and weatherheads, or even dispense with the mast altogether (with AHJ approval) as 225.18 may not apply to a fully insulated cable on a messenger.  This doesn't exempt you from providing a proper *drip loop* though!

When you're running the UF up on the messenger, you'll need to *lash* it to that messenger wire, or clip *cable saddles* onto the messenger and run the UF through those.  You'll also need to ground the messenger wire itself; this can be done by using a split bolt to clamp an 8AWG bare wire to it at the pergola end, then running that wire down to whatever you're using as a disconnect and landing it there.

Speaking of disconnects, you have a couple of options for that.  For a single circuit, a simple lightswitch, or perhaps a key-operated one if there are receptacles at the pergola, will do the trick.  A weatherproof box and cover would certainly be in order for such, though!  If your run is more substantial than that, though, you'll want to use a non-fused pullout disconnect box (air conditioner disconnect) instead.  Either way, you'll want a compression grounding wire fitting (sometimes called a "Kenny clamp") to bring the messenger ground into the box, and a second drip-loop + weathertight fitting/gland to bring the UF cable into the box via the bottom or side. (I wouldn't trust a NEMA 3R hub to seal properly against a UF fitting.)

### If you want to use conduit instead

If you wanted to use conduit instead of a MSW run for such a short distance, that is possible as well.  Given you're only spanning 3' eave-to-eave, you *could* technically do this with LFMC provided it's attached securely to both the house and pergola eaves, as the NEC permits 4½' between supports for LFMC.  However, a sturdier wiring method such as rigid conduit may be a better choice given the potential forces involved.  If you do go with rigid conduit, though, NEC 300.4(H) means that you'll need to put an expansion-deflection fitting or two in your run, though, to take up relative motion between the two buildings.  (Which can be *very* significant indeed given what gets up to shakin' where you live.)

Comment: The wall and the pergola itself are both only about 8ft tall. Would using some form of conduit instead of a suspended cable reduce the clearance needed?

Comment: @CJC -- you can't run conduit on a messenger wire, even LFMC/LFNC isn't flexible enough for that service

Comment: Could you have an overhead trellis above the walkway and mount conduit to that?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- if there's a rigid structure there, I don't see why not...

Comment: And then presumably the height requirement would go away. If the conduit were installed inside a U-shaped channel (three pieces of wood) then it would not be visible from underneath - might be a great solution. Spanning 5' is certainly easy enough.